# Why can't CLion see header files, using the WSL2 toolchain?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, wsl-2

My setup:

- Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (19045.2965)
- CLion 2020.1.3 (JetBrains)
- WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- gcc 11.3.0
- cmake 3.22.1
- gdb 12.1
- gmake 4.3

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above, `<iostream>` is flagged as "'iostream' file not found." CLion is unable to find any system headers. Whether it by the C++ standard headers or any add-on libraries, such as wxWidgets. As a result, it has difficulty seeing any of the classes, namespaces, etc., found in the headers. It has no problems seeing local project headers.

The project compiles.

I have tried adding

```
include_directories(
        SYSTEM
        includes
        /usr/include
)
```

to the `CMakeLists.txt` file. I have also tried reinstalling CLion.

I know there is a newer version of CLion available, upgrading is currently off the table.

How do I get CLion to behave?

Edit 1:
I should add CLion is installed on the host (Windows).

Comment: I have tried connecting to a remote Linux server, no difference. (Actually, it is a VirtualBox machine.) All tool chain app versions are the same.

Comment: Installed the Linux version on both WSL2 and VirtualBox, and they work. I would still like to get the Windows version to work.